# Issue after installing Virtualmin with the same Server as Mautic

Tags: webmin, virtualmin, mautic

since I didn't have a basic configuration panel, today I allowed myself to install Virtualmin on the same server as MAUTIC and then I encountered this problem when I visit my mautic Url

````
/*
 * @copyright   2014 Mautic Contributors. All rights reserved
 * @author      Mautic
 *
 * @link        http://mautic.org
 *
 * @license     GNU/GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
define('MAUTIC_ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);

// Fix for hosts that do not have date.timezone set, it will be reset based on users settings
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

require_once 'autoload.php';

use Mautic\CoreBundle\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler;
use Mautic\Middleware\MiddlewareBuilder;
use function Stack\run;

ErrorHandler::register('prod');

run((new MiddlewareBuilder(new AppKernel('prod', false)))->resolve());```

Anyone here know to fix it please ? Thank you all
````

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Check your php configs and try again. Occurs same error here.

For example: create a index page and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If page returns text instead of php page with informations, your php server has incorrect configuration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).